# Ctrl + F not working for browser page search when using Google Docs

Tags: google-drive, search, google-chrome

When I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in Google Docs, it shows the "document find view". What I would like is the "browser find view" when in Google Chrome.

What keys do I need to press to do a browser <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in Google Docs in Google Chrome? Currently the web app will take control of that hotkey combination when opened.

Comment: I don't think there is an official solution to this. Ctrl+F makes a page search and with Docs, the document IS the page, thus Chrome considers it as the same thing and it overrides the browser page search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a keyboard solution that will open the Chrome [*find bar*](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95635) even when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is redefined on the page.

Judging by the keys you normally use, you are a Windows user. On Windows, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, then press <kbd>F</kbd>. This solution uses menu shortcuts to open the find bar.

Alternatively, you can mouse click the **wrench** button and mouse click "**Find...**".

Comment: Alt-F doesn't work because it has been redefined too. The wrench works, cool =D

Answer (score 3):

Pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> has the same result as pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in most browsers and this hotkey is not used in Google Docs.